# Running Express Application in Terminal

Tags: express

Im trying to run the command 'nmp start' in terminal. However this now appears and I cant seem to run any command 'node ./bin/www'. Does anyone know what this is. All Im trying to run Express in the browser but no joy..... Anyone can give me the heads up please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your question is impossible to answer without more information. Please provide information about how you've installed the application, what cmd you're running and what the console output is

Answer (score 0):

To use `npm start` in a project, your `package.json` file must have this `script` session declared:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./<path>/<to>/<your>/<module>"
},
```

Comment: Got it working thanks...... Im piecing the puzzle together slowly but surely.....